# Django- create_user() function not saving data to database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have custom User model. I tried to create new user using create_user(), by calling it from view, but data is not getting saved to database.

### models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

### views.py

```
        user = {
         'username': generate_username(name), 'email': email,
         'password': password}
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user)
        user.is_verified = True
        user.save()
```

Comment: What happens when you call `create_user()`? Any errors?

Comment: Nope, i don't get any errors

Comment: And even User.objects.create() not creating new user.

Comment: Does the method even get executed? Have you used a debugger (or `print()`) to see what is the result of the call `user = self.model(...)`?

Comment: Yes, self.model() gets executed. I tested it with print(). On the console, user object printed, but object isn't creating in the database.

Comment: The source code for `QuerySet.create()` uses `obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)`; maybe try that in your code?

Comment: Most notably, it uses `self.db` instead of `self._db`; maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Ok, the problem has been resolved. I had instance.delete() by mistake in signal and that was causing problem